# C# Check gridview row select or not

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I want to check whether a row in a `gridview` is selected or not. how can I write if condition??

```
if (gridview-row[1].select)

{
    //do something
}

else

{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: What kind of application, ASP.Net ? WinForm ?? WPF

Answer (score 0):

youcan use `GridViewRow.RowState` property [Asp.net Gridview.RowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowstate.aspx)

```
GridViewRow row = yourGridView.SelectedRow; will give the selected row
```

and check like this

```
if(row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Selected)
    {
      //selectd
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is asp.net, you can set up a SelectedIndexChanged event on the GridView. This event will fire whenever the GridView has a new row selection. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow.aspx).

```
  <asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
       datasourceid="CustomersSource" 
       autogeneratecolumns="False"
       autogenerateselectbutton="True"
       allowpaging="True" 
       selectedindex="1"
       onselectedindexchanged="CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged" 
       runat="server" DataKeyNames="CustomerID"> ...
```

Event listener where you can obtain the selected row

```
  void CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Gets the currently selected row based on the selected index changed event
    //
    var selectedRow = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (GridView.SelectedIndex == rowIndex)
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    // do something
}
```

You can write like this.